# Git: Delete remote branch after delete local branch get an error

Tags: git, github

I merge branch A with branch B, and delete branch A. When I tried the same thing in remote repo: delete branch A, I got an error like this:

```
fajar@FAJAR-PC /e/project minggu ini/ProjectTesis (master)
$ git push origin : perbaikan_1
Username for 'https://github.com': gunungloli666
Password for 'https://gunungloli666@github.com':
error: src refspec perbaikan_1 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gunungloli666/proj_tes.gi
t'
```

I using github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your repository `perbaikan_1` is the *default* branch.
you should switch the *default* branch to `master` (or something else, that you don't want to delete) via your repository settings.

then you might want to delete-push without a space between the colon and the branch-name:

```
 git push origin :perbaikan_1
```